# Override default Oreo Foreground Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

As I correctly recall, with Android Oreo the system got more restrictive in terms of battery consumption, e.g., showing the user which app is currently running in the background draining the battery life.

This also shows in my app (scanning for BLE devices in the background, even if the app is not running in the foreground), stating

> AppName is running in the background. Tap for Details on battery and
>   data usage

My question is, *whether* and *how* I would be able to exchange this text with a more user facing notification like

> AppName is running in the background for reason XYZ

Even so with a notification with a specific icon, etc.

I already tried this by

1. Creating a custom notification channel in the application.
2. Starting the services with `startForegroundService` on Oreo devices.
3. From within the `onCreate` method of the service, I call

   ```
   startForeground(1, NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "my_channel_id")
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_icon)
               .setContentTitle("Title")
               .setContentText("AppName is running in the background for reason XYZ")
               .build())
   ```

But all what happens is the same system-generated notification saying "AppName is running in the background".

Is it even possible to change this?

Thank you for sour suggestions in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In you service create the notification in `onStartCommand()` and set its priority. Don't forget to add `android:enabled="true"` in the manifest.

**Service**

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
                    ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Test title")
                .setContentText("Test content")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

        startForeground(1, notification.build())

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<service android:name=".utils.AppService"
         android:enabled="true"/>
```